# mingw32 on Windows10 : compiling errors "cannot convert 'CRITICAL_SECTION*" for googletest (gtest-1.8.0)

Tags: windows, windows-10, googletest, mingw32

I've installed mingw32 , downloaded gtest-1.8.0 in C:\gtest-1.8.0.

I've launched the command 
C:\gtest-1.8.0\googletest\make>mingw32-make

```
g++ -isystem ../include -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread -c ../samples/sample1.cc
g++ -isystem ../include -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread -c ../samples/sample1_unittest.cc
g++ -isystem ../include -I.. -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread -c \
            ../src/gtest-all.cc
In file included from ../src/gtest-all.cc:45:0:
../src/gtest-port.cc: In constructor 'testing::internal::Mutex::Mutex()':
../src/gtest-port.cc:242:45: error: cannot convert 'CRITICAL_SECTION* {aka _CRITICAL_SECTION*}' to '_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION*' in initialization
       critical_section_(new CRITICAL_SECTION) {
                                             ^
[...]
        Makefile:57: recipe for target 'gtest-all.o' failed
        mingw32-make: *** [gtest-all.o] Error 1
```

I'm in doubt if I'm missing something